# Merge list items into single item based on matching value in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of items `List<ActivityForecast> activityForecast`:

```
ArDate       Category    Type      Arr  Dep  Slp
----------   ---------   ------   ----- ---- ----
11-08-2019     I          S        0    7     0   
11-08-2019     I          A        5    0     0
11-08-2019     I          D        0    0     6
11-08-2019     R          A        0    10    0
12-08-2019     I          A        5    0     0
```

I want something like merge this: Merge the list of similar object based on date and category and concatenate type into single column.

```
ArDate       Category    Type      Arr  Dep  Slp
----------   ---------   ------   ----- ---- ----
11-08-2019     I          S,A,D    5    7     6   
11-08-2019     R          A        0    10    0
12-08-2019     I          A        5    0     0
```

This is what i tried, using GroupBy

```
var result = activityForecast.GroupBy(c => new
            {
                c.ArrivalDate,
                c.Category
            })
                 .Select(o =>
                 {
                     return new ActivityForecast
                     {
                         ArDate = o.First().ArDate,
                         Category = o.First().Category,
                         ArrvlRms = o.First().Arr,
                         Type = o.First().Type,
                         Dep = o.First().Dep,
                         Slp = o.First().Slp
                     };
                 });
```

but this will result like this

```
ArDate       Category    Type      Arr  Dep  Slp
----------   ---------   ------   ----- ---- ----
11-08-2019     I          D        0    0     6
11-08-2019     R          A        0    10    0
12-08-2019     I          A        5    0     0
```

Comment: where is the problem? join all Type in a group `o.Select(a =>a.Type)` ... **edit:** and sum other stuff

Comment: @Downvoters: I have tried at least 60%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Sum to get `Arr`, `Dep` and `Slp` properties. And for Type, do `string.Join`. Below is the updated code:

```
var result = activityForecast.GroupBy(c => new
            {
                c.ArrivalDate,
                c.Category
            })
                 .Select(o =>
                 {
                     var first = o.First();
                     return new ActivityForecast
                     {
                         ArDate = first.ArDate,
                         Category = first.Category,
                         ArrvlRms = o.Sum(g => g.Arr),
                         Type = string.Join(",", o => o.Select(g => g.Type)),
                         Dep = o.Sum(g => g.Dep),
                         Slp = o.Sum(g => g.Slp)
                     };
                 });
```

Check [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RVvUUB) dotnet fiddle which demos the similar `stirng.Join` and `Sum` linq operations to get the grouped data.

Comment: My property type 'Type' is a string, So it cannot able to convert lambda exp to type string[]. i just used the code as @Dmitry suggested and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `GroupBy`; after grouping you should turn each *group* into *single* `ActivityForecast` instance:

```
List<ActivityForecast> activityForecast = ...

var result = activityForecast
  .GroupBy(forecast => new {
     forecast.ArDate,
     forecast.Category,
   })
  .Select(group => new ActivityForecast() {
     // These values are taken from Key:
     ArDate   = group.Key.ArDate,
     Category = group.Key.Category,

     // These values should be aggregated over group:
     // Providing that Type is string  
     Type     = string.Join(",", group.Select(item => item.Type).Distinct()),
     //TODO: put correct aggregate function here (Sum? Max?)
     Arr      = group.Sum(item => item.Arr),
     Dep      = group.Sum(item => item.Dep),
     Slp      = group.Sum(item => item.Slp),
   });
```